# Stub an Express route

Tags: node.js, express, controller, routes

I'd like to write a test that a given Express controller endpoint gets hit for a given HTTP request. Or, say, an authenticated request makes it through every middleware and hits the controller.

I don't actually care about the controller, in fact the controller is expensive, so I'd rather not run it.

Say something like:

UsersController.js

```
module.exports = {
    get: function(req, res) {
        // Simplified for example purposes. Assume this does something complex.
        res.status(200).json({id: "user123"});
    }
}
```

Then I have a Router:

```
var router;
module.exports = router = new express.Router();
router.get('/users/:id', isAuthenticated, isAdmin, logRequest, UsersController.get);
```

I'd like to write something like this in the test:

```
controllerStub = sinon.stub(UsersController, 'get', function(req, res) {
    res.status(418).json(message: "I'm a teapot");
});
request.get('http://localhost:port/users/user123', function(err, response, body) {
    response.statusCode.should.equal(418);
    controllerStub.callCount.should.equal(1);
});
```

Unfortunately I think Express modifies the function pointer in a way that stubbing the controller with Sinon doesn't actually affect the function called by Express.

Is there any way I can "reach" into the Express router and get/replace/stub the running route?

Comment: Can't you just make sure that the UsersController is stubbed before the app initialization?

Comment: That's tricky, I'd have to initialize the app before running every single test in that case...